# Android: how to access a camera instance from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

How to get a camera instance from a fragment?

Check this link below: `getCameraInstance()` is called without problems inside a `Fragment` class:

https://github.com/rexstjohn/UltimateAndroidCameraGuide/blob/master/camera/src/main/java/com/ultimate/camera/fragments/NativeCameraFragment.java

but when I try to call `getCameraInstance()`, I get this:

> cannot resolve method getCameraInstance()

```
public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment {

//...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo, container, false);


    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
```

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to change your fragment class to `extends NativeCameraFragmant` instead of `extends Fragment`.

Answer (score 3):

`getCameraInstance()` is a `static` method on the class that you linked to. If you want to have a `getCameraInstance()` method, you will need to write it yourself or use one from third-party code, such as this one.